# Did Vasudeva send Kasyapa to perform rituals to newly born Pandavas

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas

Is it true according to Vyasa Mahabharata that Vasudeva, the father of lord Krishna, sent Kasyapa, from Dwaraka, as purohit to perform all samskaras to newly born Pandavas?

Answer (score 3):

It was mentioned in  [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01124.htm) that 7 rishis did come at the time of the birth of Arjuna.  However,  it is not mentioned in the Chapters related to birth of Pandavas from  Vyasa Mahabharata that Vasudeva sent them.

> The sons of Kadru (Nagas), the son of Vinata, the Gandharvas, the
>   lords of the creation, and the **seven great Rishis, viz., Bharadwaja,
>   Kasyapa, Gautama, Viswamitra, Jamadagni, Vasishtha, and the
>   illustrious Atri** who illumined the world of old when the Sun was
>   lost, all came there. And Marichi, Angiras, Pulastya, Pulaha, Kratu,
>   Daksha the lord of creation, the Gandharvas, and Apsaras, came there
>   also

It was also mentioned that 5 sons were born at a gap of 1 year each. And, [rishis dwelling](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01125.htm) in the vicinity performed the 1st rites after birth.

> And those foremost sons born at an interval of one year after one
>   another, looked like an embodied period of five years.